# Who are the supporting characters in the game's intro cinematics?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

In the three intro cinematics, there are a couple of recurring characters. Satele Shan, the female Jedi, for instance, and Darth Malgus.

A couple of the other characters show up in official art, and in one case, even appears on the game's box.

Who is the female, red-headed bounty hunter from the Empire's intro cinematic? Is she, like Shan and Malgus, a story character, or just some box-based eye-candy?

What about the Smuggler who is being arrested during the Fall of Korriban, or the Republic Commander who rescues Shan from Malgus on Alderaan?

Are the rest of these characters meetable in game?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the red-head is [Shae Vizla](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Shae_Vizla), the smuggler [Nico Okarr](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Nico_Okarr), and the commander [Jace Malcom](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Jace_Malcom).

The intro is set at the start of the war, which is ~20 years before the time of the MMO. In that time a peace treaty was signed, but a cold war wages on when you start playing.

Comment: This looks correct - do you know if they appear in game?

Comment: I haven't had much luck finding them. According to this trailer, http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GsxdMtGs3AU Jace (you can't miss that face), Nico (towards the end, watch for the hat), and Shae (you see her in armor) *will* be along with some other characters from the intros.